# Failed to build spice on automake step

Tags: c, makefile, configure, automake

I have a problem with subdir-objects, trying to build libspice

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=$PREFIX
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I /home/shved/Projects/usr/share/aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: adding subdirectory spice-common to autoreconf
autoreconf: Entering directory `spice-common'
autoreconf: configure.ac: adding subdirectory spice-protocol to autoreconf
autoreconf: Entering directory `spice-protocol'
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I /home/shved/Projects/usr/share/aclocal --force 
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
autoreconf: Leaving directory `spice-protocol'
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, `build-aux'.
libtoolize: copying file `build-aux/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
libtoolize: copying file `m4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
automake: warnings are treated as errors
common/Makefile.am:4: warning: source file '$(srcdir)/generated_client_demarshallers.c' is in a subdirectory,
common/Makefile.am:4: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
automake: warning: possible forward-incompatibility.
automake: At least a source file is in a subdirectory, but the 'subdir-objects'
automake: automake option hasn't been enabled.  For now, the corresponding output
automake: object file(s) will be placed in the top-level directory.  However,
automake: this behaviour will change in future Automake versions: they will
automake: unconditionally cause object files to be placed in the same subdirectory
automake: of the corresponding sources.
automake: You are advised to start using 'subdir-objects' option throughout your
automake: project, to avoid future incompatibilities.
common/Makefile.am:4: warning: source file '$(srcdir)/generated_client_demarshallers1.c' is in a subdirectory,
common/Makefile.am:4: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
common/Makefile.am:4: warning: source file '$(srcdir)/generated_client_marshallers.c' is in a subdirectory,
common/Makefile.am:4: but optio./autogen.sh --prefix=$PREFIX
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I /home/shved/Projects/usr/share/aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: adding subdirectory spice-common to autoreconf
autoreconf: Entering directory `spice-common'
autoreconf: configure.ac: adding subdirectory spice-protocol to autoreconf
autoreconf: Entering directory `spice-protocol'
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I /home/shved/Projects/usr/share/aclocal --force 
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
autoreconf: Leaving directory `spice-protocol'
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, `build-aux'.
libtoolize: copying file `build-aux/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
libtoolize: copying file `m4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
automake: warnings are treated as errors
common/Makefile.am:4: warning: source file '$(srcdir)/generated_client_demarshallers.c' is in a subdirectory,
common/Makefile.am:4: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
automake: warning: possible forward-incompatibility.
automake: At least a source file is in a subdirectory, but the 'subdir-objects'
automake: automake option hasn't been enabled.  For now, the corresponding output
automake: object file(s) will be placed in the top-level directory.  However,
automake: this behaviour will change in future Automake versions: they will
automake: unconditionally cause object files to be placed in the same subdirectory
automake: of the corresponding sources.
automake: You are advised to start using 'subdir-objects' option throughout your
automake: project, to avoid future incompatibilities.
common/Makefile.am:4: warning: source file '$(srcdir)/generated_client_demarshallers1.c' is in a subdirectory,
common/Makefile.am:4: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
common/Makefile.am:4: warning: source file '$(srcdir)/generated_client_marshallers.c' is in a subdirectory,
common/Makefile.am:4: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
common/Makefile.am:4: warning: source file '$(srcdir)/generated_client_marshallers1.c' is in a subdirectory,
common/Makefile.am:4: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
common/Makefile.am:11: warning: source file '$(srcdir)/generated_server_demarshallers.c' is in a subdirectory,
common/Makefile.am:11: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
common/Makefile.am:11: warning: source file '$(srcdir)/generated_server_marshallers.c' is in a subdirectory,
common/Makefile.am:11: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

I did change nothing, only clone from git. I tried to ask at [bugzilla](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67304), but there no response.

My autoreconf version is 2.69
My automake version is 1.14

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: It seems likely that you are using a different version of automake than what they expect.  Usually the version dependencies are documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading to automake 1.13.4 resolved this problem.